# JavaFX Checkbox doesn't follow bound property's value

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, properties

I have a model that has a boolean property that can be toggled. However depending on the conditions, the property toggle may fail.

I want to bind this property to a check box in my UI, moreover if the property fails to toggle, I want the check box to remain in its previous state.

I have created a SSCCE for this given below. I have a boolean property that emulates a failed toggle from false to true by simply setting to false regardless of the argument. The check box is initially false, as is the boolean property.

I expect that when I click the check box, it will remain unset because that is the state of the booleanproperty to which it is bound. However this is not the case, it will happily toggle on.

Is there something I can do about this in the boolean property or do I need to work around this by not binding the property at all and use listeners and event handlers?

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PropertySSCCE extends Application {

    BooleanProperty property = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false) {
        @Override
        public void set(boolean newValue) {
            super.set(false);
            fireValueChangedEvent();
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Boolean v) {
            super.setValue(false);
            fireValueChangedEvent();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage aStage) throws Exception {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(property);

        Scene scene = new Scene(cb);
        aStage.setScene(scene);
        aStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code of `bindBidirectional`, when one value changes a "updating" flag is set, so that you don't get an update loop. This is the reason why it's not working. I am not aware of a better solution than custom listeners.

source: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/binding/BidirectionalBinding.java#BidirectionalBinding.BidirectionalBooleanBinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @sillyfly's comment this seems to be impossible with a binding so I created the following helper to bind a `CheckBox`'s displayed value to a boolean property and (ab)used the `Predicate` class to set and tell if the setting was OK.

```
public static void bindTogglable(CheckBox aCheckBox, BooleanExpression aBooleanExpression,
        Predicate<Boolean> aSuccess) {
    aCheckBox.setSelected(aBooleanExpression.get());
    aBooleanExpression.addListener((aObservable, aOld, aNew) -> {
        aCheckBox.setSelected(aNew);
    });

    aCheckBox.setOnAction(e -> {
        boolean value = aCheckBox.isSelected();
        boolean oldValue = aBooleanExpression.get();
        if (value != oldValue && !aSuccess.test(value)) {
            aCheckBox.setSelected(oldValue);
        }
    });
}
```

For OP's SSCCE the use would be as follows:

```
bindTogglable(cb, property, (value) -> false);
```

instead of:

```
 cb.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(property);
```